# WinAPI navigate back/forward

Tags: c++, winapi

In any web browser and in the Windows file manager and in many other applications there is support for forward and backward navigation. This always (or at least most of the time) by default works with extra mouse buttons if your mouse has any.

I want to implement this in a C++ application I'm making based on WinAPI. However I wonder how one would do this? Are the mouse buttons captured "manually" in each application that has this forward/backward navigation or is there native support for it somewhere in WinAPI?

Manually capturing the buttons is probably always an option, but if there already is an existing functionality that handles this then it seems like that should be used instead. That's probably more reliable as well.

To sum up: I want my application to correctly handle/receive backward and forward clicks from a mouse that has such buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WM_APPCOMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275.aspx) message offers the `APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_FORWARD` ("Navigate forward") and `APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD` ("Navigate backward") navigation commands. You can handle them in your application, even if it's not a browser.

The documentation has information, how and when the `WM_APPCOMMAND` is generated:

> [**DefWindowProc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572.aspx) generates the **WM_APPCOMMAND** message when it processes the [**WM_XBUTTONUP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646246.aspx) or [**WM_NCXBUTTONUP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646240.aspx) message, or when the user types an application command key.